# How to customize the P&L report

Tags: uwp

Step 1: User left click on "IconButton (iconbutton)" in "Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug"
Program: Sample.Uwp.App, 1.0.0.0, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE
UI Elements: Button, IconButton, IconButton, Button, ScrollViewer, HamburgerMenu, HamburgerMenu, Vision - Debug, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug, ApplicationFrameWindow

Step 2: User left click on "Search customer (edit)" in "Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug"
Program: Sample.Uwp.App, 1.0.0.0, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE
UI Elements: Search customer, TextBox, AutoSuggestBox, FullTextSearchControl, FullTextSearchControl, ScrollViewer, PageContent, ScrollViewer, SalesInvoice_Page, PageShell, HamburgerMenu, HamburgerMenu, Vision - Debug, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug, ApplicationFrameWindow

Step 3: User keyboard input on "Vision - Debug (window)" in "Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug" [... Tab]
Program: Sample.Uwp.App, 1.0.0.0, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE, VISION.UWP.APP.EXE
UI Elements: Vision - Debug, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, Quality Hardware (Demo) ‎- Vision - Debug, ApplicationFrameWindow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We already have a tutorial on **How to customize the report?**.
Look at https://portal.vision.com/reports/customization